# VFX video always flipped in Movie Editor

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, tracking, movie-clip-editor

I was trying to do basic Motion Tracking in Blender, so I followed a tutorial and followed all the steps, but I had the problem a lot of people have where the video is flipped upside-down, and it was flipped no matter what (even if I imported it upside-down), and I figured out how to flip it in the Video Sequencer, but when I go back into the Movie Clip Editor to do the motion tracking the video's still upside-down. By the way, it is an .MP4 file. Any ideas why this is happening?

[image: Video Sequencer (flipped properly)]

[image: Movie Clip Editor (Not properly flipped)]

Thanks in advance, too.

Comment: If you flipped it in the video sequencer, you need to render (export) it first and then re-import the exported video in the clip editor. Your clip editor is still reading the original unflipped version from your drive, that's why it's still upside down

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly! And I never would have thought of that because I had never tried rending before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, so my problem was just that the video was being loaded from the actual file, so no matter how I changed it it wouldn't be different in the Movie Clip Editor

Rendering (exporting), then re-importing the exported video and using that one worked, thank you [@mqbaka mqbaka](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278881/vfx-video-always-flipped-in-movie-editor?rq=1#comment479096_278881)
*(You commented instead of answering so I just thought I'd make sure this was answered)*.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think I solved this one. The video was taken on my samsung phone. It seems that it must place some kind of metadata into the video about its orientation. To remove this data I used a video editing program, imported the video and basically just produced it again, effectively stripping it of any meta data it may have had.

Then the vector>window option worked.

As confirmation the files I had flipped and reproduced and then tried to use with the vector>window remained flipped (as they were upside down anyway).